# Не воспроизводит аудио

Tags: android, exoplayer

Пытаюсь реализовать воспроизведение аудио из интернета через ExoPlayer, но при запуске в логах выдает ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста если кто-то сталкивался, что за ошибка и как ее лечить?

Код плеера

```
public class RadioPlayer {

    private static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private static LoopingMediaSource loopingSource;

    public static void startPlayer(String url, Context context) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.stop();
        }

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector( videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector, loadControl);

        Uri streamUri = Uri.parse(url);

        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "allradios"), bandwidthMeterA);
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        if (url.contains("m3u8")) {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, 1, null, null);
            loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
            player.prepare(loopingSource);
        } else {
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(streamUri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
            player.prepare(loopingSource);
        }

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        player.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
                player.stop();
                player.prepare(loopingSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void stopPlayer() {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

PlayerActivity

```
public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private int radioID;
    private String stream = "";
    private String radio = "";
    private String genre = "";
    private String city = "";
    private String favorites = "";
    private String img;

    private String MAYBE_ACTION = "MAYBE_ACTION";
    static boolean isPlay = false;
    ImageButton btnPLayPause;
    private ImageButton btnFavorites;
    private TextView txtRadio;
    private TextView txtCategoryCity;
    private RoundedImageView imgRadio;

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";
    private String internetStatus = "";

    BroadcastReceiver br;
    AdRequest adRequesti;
    private InterstitialAd adMob;

    BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver;
    public final static String SERVICE_PARAM = "param";
    public final static int SERVICE_STATUS = 0;
    public final static String BROADCAST_ACTION = "myradio";

    DBHeler db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        TextView txtHeaderVersion = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderVersion);
        txtHeaderVersion.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.version) + " " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

        db = new DBHeler(this);
        db.openDataBase();
        db.getWritableDatabase();

        btnPLayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPLayPause);
        btnFavorites = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
        txtRadio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtRadio);
        txtCategoryCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryCity);
        imgRadio = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRadio);

        radioID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Contract.Entry.TABLE_RADIO + " WHERE " + Contract.Entry._ID + " = " + radioID;
        Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        try {
            if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    stream = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_URL));
                    radio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_TITLE));
                    genre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORY));
                    city = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_CITY));
                    favorites = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITES));
                    img = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_IMG));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        setTitle(radio);
        txtRadio.setText(radio);
        txtCategoryCity.setText(genre + " / " + city);
        Glide.with(PlayerActivity.this).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/images/" + img + ".png")).into(imgRadio);

        if (favorites.equals("1")) {
            btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star);
        } else if (favorites.equals("0")){
            btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border);
        }

        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0) {
            startPlayerService();
        }

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                finish();
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MAYBE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(br, intentFilter);
    }

    public void startPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_STREAM, stream);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(PlayerService.KEY_RADIO, radio);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = true;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stop);
    }

    private void stopPlayerService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.this, PlayerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
        isPlay = false;
        btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver NetworkChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            internetStatus = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, internetStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                int serviceStatus = intent.getIntExtra(SERVICE_PARAM, 0);

                if (serviceStatus == SERVICE_STATUS) {
                    btnPLayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(serviceReceiver, filter);

        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
        registerReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (NetworkChangeReceiver != null) unregisterReceiver(NetworkChangeReceiver);

        unregisterReceiver(br);

        unregisterReceiver(serviceReceiver);
    }

    public void onPlayPause(View view) {
        if (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(this) != 0 ) {
            if (isPlay) {
                stopPlayerService();
            } else {
                startPlayerService();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Нет подключения к интернету", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopPlayerService();
        }
    }

}
```

Сервис

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    public static Context context;
    boolean isPlay = false;
    String stream;
    String radio;
    Notification notification;

    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    public static final String KEY_STREAM = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_STREAM";
    public static final String KEY_RADIO = PlayerService.class.getSimpleName() + ".KEY_RADIO";

    final String myLog = "LOG";

    private void showNotification() {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        closeIntent.setAction(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

        int notifyId = 1;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String channelID = "cradioID"; 
            CharSequence cannelName = "Radio Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW; 

            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, cannelName, importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(PlayerService.this, channelID)
                    .setContentTitle("Играет: " + radio)
                    .setContentText("Открыть")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setChannelId(channelID)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

            startForeground(PlayerConstants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        context = this;
        this.stream = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_STREAM);
        this.radio = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_RADIO);

        if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = true;

            showNotification();

            RadioPlayer.startPlayer(stream, this);
        } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(PlayerConstants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            isPlay = false;

            Intent brIntent = new Intent(PlayerActivity.BROADCAST_ACTION);
            brIntent.putExtra(PlayerActivity.SERVICE_PARAM, 0);
            sendBroadcast(brIntent);

            RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
            stopForeground(true);
            PlayerActivity.isPlay = false;
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        RadioPlayer.stopPlayer();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Caused by:
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException:
>   AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(48000, 12, 48000) at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack.checkAudioTrackInitialized(AudioTrack.java:974)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:521)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:332)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:891) 
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:484) 
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479) 
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:315)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)  at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40) 
>   09-19 17:52:03.101 20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.121
>   20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.157 20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.179
>   20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.220 20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.242
>   20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.274 20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.289
>   20368-20440/myradio E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param
>   0x000085b5 09-19 17:52:03.312 20368-20529/myradio I/OMXClient: Using
>   client-side OMX mux. 09-19 17:52:03.328 20368-20440/myradio
>   E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000085b5 09-19
>   17:52:03.334 20368-20468/myradio E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not
>   create track, status: -12 09-19 17:52:03.334 20368-20468/myradio
>   E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error -12 initializing AudioTrack 09-19 17:52:03.335
>   20368-20468/myradio E/android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -20 when
>   initializing AudioTrack. 09-19 17:52:03.335 20368-20468/myradio
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error.
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.MediaCodecAudioRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioRenderer.java:339)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:891)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:484)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:479)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:315)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)

Comment: Сам код можно глянуть?

Comment: В вопрос добавила классы плеера, активити и сервиса

Comment: Предположу, что вместо `new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(` нужно использовать `new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory`.

Comment: AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory такого класса нет в Exoplayer. Во всяком случае в версии что я использую implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.1.0'